# I’ve been trying to solve this derivative problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I find the derivative of this function using the quotient rule?

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{(x^4-2/x)^4}$$

Comment: Where are you stuck ?

Comment: $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x^5-2+2}{(x^5-2)^4}=\frac{1}{(x^5-2)^3}+\frac{2}{(x^5-2)^4}$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} \implies f'(x)=\frac{g'(x)h(x)-h'(x)g(x)}{h^2(x)}$$

with

- $g(x)=x$
- $h(x)=(x^4-2/x)^4$

We van also simplify $f(x)$ to obtain

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{(x^4-2/x)^4}=\frac{x^5}{(x^5-2)^4}$$

with

- $g(x)=x^5$
- $h(x)=(x^5-2)^4$

Comment: Hi, I tried that but this is the answer I got and it’s apparently wrong. This is my answer:                    ((5x^4)[(-3x^5)-2])/((x^5)-2)^5

Comment: @AliyaShaikh It seems to be correct according to [wolfy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+x%5E5%2F(x%5E5-2)%5E4). What is the given solution?

Comment: I unfortunately don’t have the solution to the problem

Comment: @AliyaShaikh Then wht are you stating that it is aparently wrong? It is correct!

Comment: If I read in the correct way your solution is $$\frac{5x^4(-3x^5-2)}{(x^5-2)^5}$$

Comment: I guess The website I’m doing my webwork assignment on made a mistake then. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: @AliyaShaikh Maybe there is some issue with the format to follow to write the answer on the website. Take a look the the given guidelines.

Comment: I’m pretty sure I did it properly since I answered 19 other questions correctly, thanks anyways.

Comment: I found the mistake so basically the simplified numerator is supposed to be x^4 and not x^5

Comment: The result you have shown here seems correct to me!

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=\frac{1(x^4-2/x)^4-x\,4(4x^3+2/x^2)(x^4-2/x)^3}{(x^4-2/x)^8}.$$